# MVC optional body parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to wire up a webhook from a 3rd party system.

When creating the subscription it hits the URL i provide and requires a validated token returned to create the hook.

When the event is triggered the hook posts to the same URL i provided with data in the body.

How can I get a Core 2.1 MVC controller/routing to see these as either two different methods on the controller or a method signature where the complex object is optional?

Either two POST methods (this creates ambiguity exception)

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(){}
public async Task<IActionResult> Index([FromBody] ComplexObject co){}
```

or complexObject is optional (if not it throws a  Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type '"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.SerializableError" on the subscription creation step.)

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index([FromBody] ComplexObject co){}
```

Comment: What if you delete the parameterless method, and then retain the other one.
Now the same link will go to your parameterized method, when the route is hit and no `body` was passed, the parameter value will be null. In that way, you can just `null` check and react based on that

Comment: That wont work.  With just the parameter method it has the SerializableError when no object exists in the body.

Comment: I did get it to work by using only the Index() method signature and checking the body and pulling the object out manually.  Not very pretty api.

Comment: Well I tried it on my end, created a post action with a parameter, then on postman i sent an empty body, it went through with the object being null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the empty parameter method signature and checked the body for data.  Not ideal.

Answer (score 2):

Another way around this :

```
public class AllowBindToNullAttribute : ModelBinderAttribute
{
    public AllowBindToNullAttribute()
        : base(typeof(AllowBindToNullBinder))
    {

    }

    public class AllowBindToNullBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var stream = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Body;
            string body;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }

            var instance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(body, bindingContext.ModelType);
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(instance);
        }
    }
}
```

You'd use it like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(
    [FromBody] [AllowBindToNull] ComplexObject co = null){}
```

Comment: One note though, depending on the deserialization settings, this might fail in a runtime (deserialization) due to wrong json format, so for instance if it is camel case on the backend and data is sent from client in pascal case it will fail (object will contain empty properties).  So, all converters should be set the same, as it was set up during startup.

Comment: That's a good point @negyxo.  It's a good idea to wrap at least the call to DeserializeObject in a try/catch, and report failures via bindingContext.Result, rather than letting an exception like that get thrown from this method.

Comment: Well, I am not sure, maybe for some cases it is a good solution to catch exception on that, but I wouldn't. My comment was regarding deserialization and when I say it could fail in a runtime, I mean it won't trigger an exception, it will just fail to give you an object. For instance, in my case when I used this method, all properties (on target object) were null, and also in my service configuration I had JsonStringEnumConverter set for Json options, so in order to correctly deserialize an object, you need to use the same logic as ASP .NET Core does. Nevertheless, this solution works great.